# SOA Design, Web services & OOP

Tags: oop, jakarta-ee, soap, jax-ws, middleware

At work (bank) we are re-designing our MW / Web services. We are using bottom-up approach to build those services. We are using Java, jax-ws. So I need to create rules to be followed. So I have 2 questions so far:

1. Should we create types to our objects fields, i.e. in class Client, should we create a CellPhone object or use simply string for that. I can see the pros & cons , object will be become heavy weight, but easy to validate & control.

Any other ideas ?

1. Should we be using SOAP built-in fault or create our own error status code (maybe in the SOAP header). I really like the SOAP fault because of the direct mapping to Java Exception.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Some answers: 
1. Bare in mind that Web Services (I assume you're talking about SOAP-based WS, 
 as you mentioned jax-ws and not jax-rs) use SOAP which is an XML based protocol. 
2. For every class you create, you will have a type in your WSDL file. 
3. The SOAP envelope (which holds the "body" of your message will also hold additional XML element to denote the cellphone - you're creating more traffic.

To conclude 1 - 3 and the fact you're talking about CellPhone, I don't understand why you need to have class for this. 
 
Are you taking about a CellPhoen class that actually models a CellPhone 
(i.e - the cell-phone device, with properties like "vendor", "operator" ,etc..) or are you  talking about the cell phone number? 
 If this is just Cell-Phone number, then my recommendation, based on 1-3 is still valid. 
To handle validation: 
You can use many validator fameworks in order to validate phone number. 
There is even a [JSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_Validation) in Java for validation. 
I recommend you to look at here to read about the [Hibernate-Validator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/) framework which conforms to JSR 303. 
You can also download the source of [oVirt](http://www.ovirt.org) open source project , 
and take a look at oVirt-engine (look at ovirt-engine/backend/manager/modules/common) at our BusinessEntiies and see some "real life" examples on how to use these validators. 
Regarding fault - you can create your own Faults, and map them to Java exceptions, I see no harm there.